# How to open a complete preferences dialog via custom button?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, working-set

I'm implementing a configuration dialog for custom `IWorkingSets`. These sets consist of selected projects but also two additional configurations, which have their own properties pages. I've already managed to implement a functioning properties dialog for these working sets, which can be found by right-clicking them and selecting `Properties` in the `Project Explorer`, but now I'd like to open that `PropertyDialog` via a button in my custom configuration dialog.

I've tried to use `PropertyDialog`, but that dialog is not API. Is there another way to open the properties dialog programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil` provides an official API for the property dialog  with three `createPropertyDialogOn` methods.

Comment: Here's the wiki page for exactly that usecase: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_launch_the_preference_page_that_belongs_to_my_plug-in%3F